# Chrome Extension: Is there a way to execute popup.js before clicking on the extension icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm building a chrome extension that has a popup, an options page, and content scripts. So far, I'm able to store preferences set on the options page and get them using popup.js. The popup.js makes a couple of public API calls to get some information X.

**What I'm stuck on:**

I need to be able to run/execute popup.js when the DOM loads, *before the extension icon is clicked*, so that information X can be injected into the DOM via the content scripts.

**My question:**

Is there a way to execute popup.js before clicking on the extension icon? (Right now, the content scripts loads fine displaying information X, after the the extension icon is clicked)

Comment: Simply don't use the popup. Do the API calls in your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was under the impression that chrome storage wasn't supported for content scripts (I needed user preferences from the options page to make the API calls), but I was wrong - I'm able to make the API calls in my content scripts like you suggested, and it seems to work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is fully supported for content scripts, so there is no need to communicate the user preferences from the options page to the content scripts via popup.js or background.js.

With this in mind, I'm able to access user preferences directly to make the API calls in the content scripts, using `storage.sync`